# Can not set java.lang.String field to java.lang.String

Tags: java, hibernate, sockets, server

I am currently developing a small MMO application with a socket server. The database i am using is PostgreSQL and i am using the Hibernate ORM. 
I stumbled on to a exeption when requesting all the avatars an single user owns.

I got 3 classes involed, those are :

- GameServerClient
- Database
- Database.Queries

When the user (client application) sends a request to the server via the sockets, a method is called which should return a JsonString of the all the Avatars.

How ever, using the HQL query `from UserOwnsAvatar where user = :username` and puting the result in an ArrayList of the UserOwnsAvatar object it returns an `Can not set java.lang.String field nl.marcusink.mmo.server.database.table.User.username to java.lang.String`

the full stackTrace is :

```
org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String nl.marcusink.mmo.server.database.table.User.username] by reflection for persistent property [nl.marcusink.mmo.server.database.table.User#username] : Mjollnir94
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4594)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.toLoggableString(EntityType.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter.toString(EntityPrinter.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.QueryParameters.traceParameters(QueryParameters.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
    at nl.marcusink.mmo.server.database.Database$Queries.avatarsRequest(Database.java:134)
    at nl.marcusink.mmo.server.connection.GameServerClient.run(GameServerClient.java:91)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field nl.marcusink.mmo.server.database.table.User.username to java.lang.String
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:39)
    ... 11 more
```

the query code is :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from UserOwnsAvatar where user = :username");
query.setParameter("username", username);
ArrayList<UserOwnsAvatar> ownedAvatars = (ArrayList<UserOwnsAvatar>) query.list();
```

The last line is the cause of the error, any ideas?

EDIT

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "username", nullable = false)
private User user;

@Id
@OneToOne(targetEntity = Avatar.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "avatar", nullable = false, unique = true)
private Avatar avatar;
```

The username here is equal to the username of the User object, which is :

```
@Id
@Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String username;
```

Comment: can you please show the codes related to `username`...

Comment: maybe you need to add `public void setUsername(String username) {this.username = username;}` to the `User` class.

Comment: I generated all the getters and setters for every table class. the `public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }` is one of them. That couldnt be the problem i think

Comment: Dont mind me for correcting my self : query : `user` tablefield : `username`

Comment: Thanks for the help though! I am blind for this kind of mistakes...

Comment: Oh that error message is a mess. As you can see from the stack trace, it attempts to `get` but produces an error message “cannot set”. After looking at the source code of `UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl .ensureObj`, I conclude that, despite the error message focusing on the value, it’s the *instance*, on which the the attempt was made, that is not of type `User`…

Comment: @Marcel may i know how u resolved this problem.Now the same problem i am getting now

Comment: @RaviKumarRavanam I found my qeurying for a field called `user` where the column name was `username`. This was the reason of my error. 
You probable fixed it yourself by now. Was it the same problem?

Comment: Yes same problem. Thanks for replying....

Answer (score 3):

You will have to set the complete (or object with only relevant fields) instead of one particular value of that object.

What I understood is you are trying to set a `String` while setting the parameter, but the column is of type `User`. Hibernate is trying to call the `getUsername` method on `String` and that's why the error.

So change your code to something like this:

```
User user = getSomeUser();
Query query = session.createQuery("from UserOwnsAvatar where user.username =  :username");
query.setParameter("username", user);
```

Comment: Your idea was correct, but you're sample code needed an edit.  It fixed a similar problem I was having.

Answer (score 1):

user = :username is incorrect. user is not a string field of the entity. Either use a join or use hibernate criteria to create a alias for User and add a restriction, for ex,  .add(Restriction.eq("user.username",username).